# Re-ordering Remote Desktop Connections

Tags: remote-desktop, windows

I have the adminpak.msi installed so that I can use the Remote Desktop MMC to connect to all of my servers. As I add a server, it goes to the bottom of the list of available servers. I can't find out how to re-order them into more logical groupings, or at least alphabetical. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

[Royal TS](http://www.code4ward.net/main/RoyalTS/Overview.aspx) can help you manage/organize your Remote Desktop connections. Also [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/) may do something similar. An alternative would be to create Remote Desktop shortcuts for each connection and store them in a folder where they can be sorted by name.

Comment: +1 for Terminals. Not exactly perfect deployment (probably just a ZIP of the developer's BIN folder ;)) but IMO so much better in daily use than MMC

Comment: A couple years ago I used Royal TS. Then I found mRemote and have been using it ever since. Either are definitely better than MMC :-)

Comment: problem is that RoyalTS and all implementations like it dont have very good support for "Network Level Authentication" although it claims that it does.   That bit me many times and Ive tried all the competing programs as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend a free application that I've been using for the last few weeks (and I am in no other way affiliated with), called [**RD Tabs** (by **Avian Waves**)](http://www.avianwaves.com/tech/tools/RDTabs/).  The tool is very flexible, allowing you to create multiple panes, each containing multiple tabs, with quick thumbnail preview access, keyboard shortcuts to just about every feature (great for people that don't like to be forced to use a mouse), and even command line / script automation of the tool.  Sorting and grouping involves nothing more than drag and drop, and you can import your existing Remote Desktop configuration file(s) with ease.

Comment: +1 I recently started using this also and now canNOT live without it!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Looks like the msc file has an encrypted area that is just not accessible. So I found a script from Brett Clarke at http://twistingthewick.org. I've modified it a bit to add structure and login information. It uses our old friend SendKeys.

You need to create a CSV with:

*server-name-or-ip,description,userid,domain*

one per line for each server. You'll have to sort this the way you want it.

You can also add a line to break things up into separate ad-ins using the syntax:

*---,some-name,,*

some-name is not used; each section is named Remote Desktops. If someone can figure out how to change the name, please let me know.

For now, this seems to work, and allows re-building any time you need to add a server. You might need to tweak the delays on your system.

Oh, and this probably won't work on Vista or Windows 7 as the SendKeys method has been disabled for security purposes.

I like to share drives, so this script checks that box. You can modify it to do pretty much anything you need.

First, though, you need to start out with a blank tsmmc.msc file. Open MMC and add a Remote Desktops snap-in. The script wants it called blanktsmmc.msc in c:\Projects\SortMmc. Of course, you'll need to have the Windows Admin Pak loaded.

Script is utilitarian, designed for speed of coding, not elegance. If you make improvements, please share.

And I'm new here. If you like this, I could use some Karma!

```
' CreateTSMMC.vbs
' Script to re-create tsmmc entries in order
' Author: Brett Clarke http://twistingthewick.org
' Version: 0.1 – 21/06/2007
'
' Updated by Brian Travis, adding login and drive info
' Version: 0.2 - 2009-08-26
'———————————————————————

'Declare some variables
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Dim objShell, objFSO, objFileCopy, objDictionary, objTextFile
Dim strBlankMMC, strWorkingMMC, strTemplate, strNextLine
Dim arrRDPList
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
strBlankMMC = "c:\Projects\SortTsmmc\blanktsmmc.msc"
strWorkingMMC = "c:\windows\system32\tsmmc.msc"
strTemplate = "c:\Projects\SortTsmmc\tsmmc.csv"
Set objFileCopy = objFSO.GetFile(strBlankMMC)
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strTemplate, ForReading)

' copy the blank template file over the working file
objFileCopy.Copy (strWorkingMMC)

' start up MMC
objShell.Run "c:\windows\system32\tsmmc.msc"

' wait for the app to start
Wscript.Sleep 1500

' get to the plugin
objShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"

' read the CSV file, and parse the entries into the MMC session
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
    arrRDPList = Split(strNextLine , ",")

    if arrRDPList(0) = "---" then
        ' create a new group
        objShell.SendKeys "%f"
        objShell.SendKeys "m"
        objShell.SendKeys "%d"
        objShell.SendKeys "rem"
        objShell.SendKeys "%a"
        objShell.SendKeys "%c"
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        objShell.SendKeys "{END}"
    else
        objShell.SendKeys "+{F10}"
        objShell.SendKeys "A"
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(0)
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep 100
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep 100
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(1)

        Wscript.Sleep 100
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep 100
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(2)

        Wscript.Sleep 100
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(3)

        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys " "

        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Wscript.Sleep 100

        ' turn on drive sharing
        Wscript.Sleep 100
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys "{END}"
        objShell.SendKeys "+{F10}"
        objShell.SendKeys "r"
        objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
        objShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        objShell.SendKeys " "
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

        ' get back to left column
        objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"  
    end if   
Loop

objShell.SendKeys "^s"

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the buttons/fields/options (or whatnot) changed in my version of Remote Desktops (v5.2.3790.0), but if anyone is having trouble getting v0.1 or v0.2 to build the RDs, here's a v0.3 with my very minor changes that finally got it automating correctly on my XP machine. Hope this helps.

PREREQS (See v0.1, v0.2 posts for details on how to make these files):

- Blank tsmmc.msc file in current directory called blanktsmmc.msc.
- tsmmc.csv file in current directory in appropriate format.

Example CSV file broken up into sections:

```
    ---[AGENTS]---,,,
    agent-pc,,neo,thematrix
    agentsmith-pc,,neo,thematrix
    ---,,,
    ---[THEMATRIX]---,,,
    merovingian-pc,,neo,thematrix
    theoracle-pc,,neo,thematrix
    thesource-pc,,neo,thematrix
    ---,,,
    ---[ZION]---,,,
    cypher-lt,,neo,thematrix
    morpheus-pc,,neo,thematrix
    tank-lt,,neo,thematrix
    trinity-pc,,neo,thematrix
```

Revised v0.3 code:

```
' CreateTSMMC.vbs
' Script to re-create tsmmc entries in order
' Author: Brett Clarke http://twistingthewick.org
' Version: 0.1 – 21/06/2007
'
' Updated by Brian Travis, adding login and drive info
' Version: 0.2 - 2009-08-26
'
' Updated by Jack Hamilton, to make it work in Remote Desktops v5.2.3790.0
' Version: 0.3 - 2012-08-15
'
' NOTES: 
' (1) If you get subscript out of range error, check your CSV for any blank lines 
' or lines with too many commas and fix/delete them.
'
' (2) Be sure to close all programs before running, especially those like email
' or instant messaging that can pop up a notification window causing the 
' window focus to change and thereby interrupt the automation process.
'———————————————————————

'Declare some variables
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const Sleep_Long_Pause = 1500
Const Sleep_Between_Keys = 200
Dim objShell, objFSO, objFileCopy, objDictionary, objTextFile
Dim strBlankMMC, strWorkingMMC, strTemplate, strNextLine
Dim arrRDPList
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
strBlankMMC = ".\blanktsmmc.msc"
strWorkingMMC = "c:\windows\system32\tsmmc.msc"
strTemplate = ".\tsmmc.csv"
Set objFileCopy = objFSO.GetFile(strBlankMMC)
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strTemplate, ForReading)

' copy the blank template file over the working file
objFileCopy.Copy (strWorkingMMC)

' start up MMC
objShell.Run "c:\windows\system32\tsmmc.msc"

' wait for the app to start
Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Long_Pause

' get to the plugin
objShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"

' read the CSV file, and parse the entries into the MMC session
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
    arrRDPList = Split(strNextLine , ",")

    if arrRDPList(0) = "---" Then
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' create a new group
        objShell.SendKeys "%f"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "m"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "%d"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "rem"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "%a"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "%c"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{END}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
    Else
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "+{F10}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' Add Connection
        objShell.SendKeys "A"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' IP/Hostname
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(0)
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' skip Browse button
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' Description
        If arrRDPList(1) = "" Then
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(0)
        Else
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(1)
        End If
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' Skip "Connect to Console"
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' Username
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(2)
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' Skip Password
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        ' Domain
        objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(3)
        ' Skip "Save Password"
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
    end if   
Loop

' get back to left column
objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"  
Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys

objShell.SendKeys "^s"

WScript.Quit
```

---

FYI, for anyone still using Brett's & Brian's solution, here's my most recent modification for Remote Desktops (tsmmc) on Windows 7 (64-bit, in).

NOTE: The blanktsmmc file is no longer needed. tsmmc.csv format residing in same directory as VB script is still same, where desc, user, domain are optional (just leave as "server,,,"). The first line of each group is a bogus connection name used just for identifying the group. The ---,,, notates that a new RemoteDesktop group should be made:

```
---[GroupA]---,,,
server,desc,user,domain
server,desc,user,domain
---,,,
---[GroupB]---,,,
server,desc,user,domain
server,desc,user,domain
---,,,
---[GroupC]---,,,
server,desc,user,domain
server,desc,user,domain
```

---

```
' CreateTSMMC.vbs
' Script to re-create tsmmc entries in order
' Author: Brett Clarke http://twistingthewick.org
' Version: 0.1 – 21/06/2007
'
' Updated by Brian Travis, adding login and drive info
' Version: 0.2 - 2009-08-26
'
' Updated by Jack Hamilton, to make it work in Remote Desktops v5.2.3790.0
' Version: 0.3 - 2012-08-15
'
' Updated by Jack Hamilton, to allow more sleep on Remote Desktops launch
' to allow application to get focus before commands executed.
' Version: 0.4 - 2012-12-27
'
' Updated by Jack Hamilton for Windows 7. You cannot 
' overwrite c:\windows\system32\tsmmc.msc, so added step at the end
' where user is prompted to Save As. User can then just execute
' using the new msc filename or create shortcut.
' Version: 0.5 - 2013-01-09
'
' NOTES: 
' (1) If you get subscript out of range error, check your CSV for any blank lines 
' or lines with too many commas and fix/delete them.
'
' (2) Be sure to close all programs before running, especially those like email
' or instant messaging that can pop up a notification window causing the 
' window focus to change and thereby interrupt the automation process.
'
'———————————————————————

'Declare some variables
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const Sleep_Long_Pause = 1000
Const Sleep_Between_Keys = 250
Dim objShell, objFSO, objFileCopy, objDictionary, objTextFile
Dim strWorkingMMC, strTemplate, strNextLine
Dim arrRDPList
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
strWorkingMMC = "c:\windows\system32\tsmmc.msc"
strTemplate = ".\tsmmc.csv"
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strTemplate, ForReading)

' start up MMC
objShell.Run strWorkingMMC

' wait for the app to start
' NOTE: We need to have enough time for the 
' Remote Desktops application to launch
' else MANY weird, bad things can happen
' if we don't have focus on the application
' else random commands start getting executed.
' Add more sleeps if app is slow to launch 
' on this particular PC.

Wscript.Sleep (Sleep_Long_Pause * 5)

' get to the plugin
objShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"

' read the CSV file, and parse the entries into the MMC session
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
    arrRDPList = Split(strNextLine , ",")

    if arrRDPList(0) = "---" Then
        ' create a new group

    ' Open File Menu
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "%f"

        ' Add/Remove Snap-In
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "m"

        ' Highlight Remote Desktops Snap-In
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "Remote Desktops"

            ' Add the highlighted available snap-in on left column
            ' over to the right-column
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "%a"

            ' Click OK
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

            ' Move to bottom snap-in
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{END}"

        ' End create new group

    Else

        ' Create new server connection

        ' Show Menu
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "+{F10}"

        ' Add Connection
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "A"

        ' IP/Hostname
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        If arrRDPList(1) = "" Then
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(0)
        Else
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(1)
        End If

            ' Tab
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

        ' Username, Domain Info
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        If arrRDPList(3) = "" Then
            ' Just Username, No Domain
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(2)
        Else
                ' Username@Domain
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(2)
            objShell.SendKeys "@"
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(3)
        End If

            ' Tab
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

        ' Save Password
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys " "

            ' Tab
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

        ' Browse button (skip)
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

        ' Description
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        If arrRDPList(1) = "" Then
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(0)
        Else
            objShell.SendKeys arrRDPList(1)
        End If

        ' Skip "Connect to Console (w /admin option)"
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

            ' Click OK
        Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

        ' End create new server connection
    end if   
Loop

' Return to left-side column
Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"  


    ' Open File Menu
Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
objShell.SendKeys "%f"

    ' Open Save As to prompt user to save with new name.
Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys
objShell.SendKeys "a"

    ' Quit Program    
Wscript.Sleep Sleep_Between_Keys    
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Here's an update on Jack Hamleton's Jan 9 post for Win7 (64-bit). His solution works perfectly with my Microsoft RDP Version 6.1.7601.17514. Spaces are not allowed in the server description field, but otherwise it worked perfectly, recreating my rearranged server list as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In the tsmmc.msc there is a  section that can be modified. If you add another String ID="#" then you can associate that ID with any String Name="Name" ID=#